# Why generative models in Machine Learning are Boltzmann distribution-backed?

Tags: unsupervised-learning, generative-models, maximum-entropy

I learned from [this review paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370157319300766) that MaxEnt models naturally display a Boltzmann distribution for the data samples, it comes from the Principle of Maximum Entropy. But I could not understand why this distribution is extended to other generative models used in unsupervised learning, e.g. Restricted Boltzmann Machines.

MaxEnt are generative models, but a generative model is not necessarily PME-backed, is it?